# What is the best method to update a sql table using python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pymysql
import configparser
import datetime
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('/var/www/cgi-bin/configs/local_config.ini')
try:
    db = pymysql.connect(host=config['mysqlDB']['host'], user=config['mysqlDB']['user'],
                         password=config['mysqlDB']['password'], database=config['mysqlDB']['database'],
                         port=int(config['mysqlDB']['port']), autocommit=True, connect_timeout=1000)
    cursor = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
except pymysql.err.OperationalError as e:
    print("Database Connection Failure " + str(e))
    subject_msg = "Database Connection Failure"
    exit(0)
updation_note = "Test updation note"
note_time_updation = "9AM"
write_id = 10234
cursor.execute("UPDATE kanon_table SET writes=%s , updated_at=%s WHERE write_id=%s",
               (str(updation_note), str(note_time_updation), str(write_id)))
```

Is there any best solution to write update query using python. Is it good to write in this manner. Do we need to commit after the update has done